# Need help in inequality question(sorry question is too long for title)

Tags: inequality

Question

> Let $n > 3$ be an integer and let $1 < a_1 \leq a_2 \leq a_3 \leq \ldots \leq a_n$ such that $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \ldots + a_n = 2n$.
> Prove that there exist $n$ real numbers such that $a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_{n-1} + a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_{n-2} + \ldots + a_1 \cdot a_2 + a_1 + 2 < a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_n$.

My answer

Let $x = a_1 + 1$. Then $a_1 = x - 1$, so
$\begin{align*}
&a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_{n-1} + a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_{n-2} + \ldots + a_1 \cdot a_2 + a_1 + 2 \\
&= (x - 1)x(x + 1) \cdots (n - 2) + (x - 1)x(x + 1) \cdots (n - 3) + \ldots + (x - 1)x(x + 1) + x - 1 + 2 \\
&= x(x + 1) \cdots (n - 1) + 2.
\end{align*}$

Also,
$a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_n = x(x + 1) \cdots (n)$.
$x(x + 1) \cdots (n - 1) + 2 < x(x + 1) \cdots (n)$.
This simplifies to $2 < x(n - 1)$.
Since $1 < a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_n$, $x = a_1 + 1 > 1$.
Also, $n > 3$, so $n - 1 > 2$.
We can take $a_1 = x - 1$, $a_2 = x$, $a_3 = x + 1$, $\dots$, $a_n = n$.
For if $n = 4$, we can take $x = 4$, so $a_1 = 3$, $a_2 = 4$, $a_3 = 5$, and $a_4 = 6$. This satisfies the given conditions.

Comment: This is hard to read, but it looks like you are asking a question and answering it, so what is left for us to do?

Comment: Yeah I answered my question but that was wrong

Comment: Then maybe you should edit the question to clarify things? Also, to fix some of the TeX.

Comment: @GerryMyerson now you can check

Comment: This is still quite confusing. In your answer, it seems that you assumee that $a_1$, $a_2$, etc is a sequence of consecutive integers. Is this true? For the TeX formatting: please use double dollar signs around equations that should be on their own line. This will make it easier to read.

Comment: Yeah, this is unclear. I get the condition that you have $n$ (real?) numbers, all greater than $1$, such that their sum is $2n$. What's unclear is the proposition: We are asked to prove that there exist $n$ (further?) real numbers such that the sum of the partial products, plus $2$, is less than the total product—i.e., that $2+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \prod_{k=1}^j a_k < \prod_{k=1}^n a_k$. But there are no other real numbers named (e.g., $b_1, \ldots, b_m$). So is the same set of $n$ numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ supposed to satisfy both constraints? Or is it that the first condition implies the second?

Comment: But then your example at the end doesn't satisfy the initial condition $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4 < 2 \times 4 = 8$. Can you kindly clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are too many variables and two conditions to be handled, for simplicity, we assume $a_1=a_2=a_3=\ldots=a_{n-2}=1$. Then, we have
$$a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{n} = n-2+a_{n-1}+a_n=2n\implies a_{n-1}=n+2-a_{n}.$$
Similarly, we have
$$a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_{n-1} + a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_{n-2} + \ldots + a_1 \cdot a_2 + a_1 + 2 < a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_n\\
\implies a_{n-1}+n-2+2<a_{n-1}a_{n}\\ 
\implies n+2-a_{n}+n<(n+2-a_{n})a_{n} \\
\implies a_{n}^2 -(n+3)a_{n}+2n+2<0\\
\implies 1\leq a_{n}<\frac{n+3+\sqrt{n^2-6n+1}}{2}<\frac{n+3+\sqrt{n^2-2n+1}}{2}=n+1.$$
Hence, we have
$$a_{n-1}=n+2-a_n>n+2-(n+1)=1.$$
Therefore, the set of $n$ real numbers such that $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_{n-1}=1,a_{n-1}=1+\epsilon$ and $a_n=n+1-\epsilon$, for $0<\epsilon<n/2$ satisfies the constraint.